# OpenShift 3 GitHub Webhook Setup

Tags: github, openshift, webhooks

I have managed to create on **OpenShift 3** a project and an app that uses **Tomcat 8**.

I have managed to get it working in **Eclipse Oxygen** and the code can be pushed to **GitHub**.

I can make changes to the code in the **Eclipse IDE**, push the changes to **GitHub** and then in **Openshift Online**, I can manually build. I can see the change out on the web, so all is well so far.

I have tried to get the **GitHub Webhook** working but so far, I am unsuccessful.

---

**In OpenShift Online:**

Following instructions here: [Triggering Builds](https://docs.openshift.com/online/dev_guide/builds/triggering_builds.html#webhook-triggers)

Then running the following command:

```
./oc describe bc myapp
```

Gives the output:

```
Name:           myapp
Namespace:      my-project-1
Created:        24 hours ago
Labels:         app=myapp
Annotations:    openshift.io/generated-by=OpenShiftNewApp
Latest Version: 8

Strategy:       Source
URL:            https://github.com/<MyCompanyName>/os-sample-java-web.git
From Image:     ImageStreamTag openshift/jboss-webserver30-tomcat8-openshift:latest
Output to:      ImageStreamTag myapp:latest

Build Run Policy:       Serial
Triggered by:           ImageChange, Config
Webhook GitHub:
    URL:    https://api.starter-ca-central-1.openshift.com:443/oapi/v1/namespaces/my-project-1/buildconfigs/myapp/webhooks/Geglxxxxxthk0u/github
Webhook Generic:
    URL:            https://api.starter-ca-central-1.openshift.com:443/oapi/v1/namespaces/my-project-1/buildconfigs/myapp/webhooks/SiyGxxxxxxxx7oHLP/generic
    AllowEnv:       false
```

---

**In GitHub Create Webhook:**

Payload URL

```
https://api.starter-ca-central-1.openshift.com/oapi/v1/namespaces/my-project-1/buildconfigs/myapp/webhooks/Geglxxxxxthk0u/github
```

Content Type

```
application/json
```

Secret

```
Geglxxxxxthk0u
```

Note. The ping on the webhook in GitHub got a green tick and status 200 so it looks ok.

---

The above password can also be seen in the **OpenShift Online** page **Edit Build Config myapp** as:
`triggers:
    - github:
        secret: Geglxxxxxthk0u
      type: GitHub`

So it looks right to me.

**But it does not work, so what am I missing?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't enter the secret in GitHub. The secret is included in the payload URL.

Just for clarity, using your original fields entered, this should be:

- Payload URL: `https://api.starter-ca-central-1.openshift.com/oapi/v1/namespaces/my-project-1/buildconfigs/myapp/webhooks/Geglxxxxxthk0u/github`
- Content Type: `application/json`
- Secret: (leave blank)

Comment: Thanks but it still does not trigger a build. I even deleted the old web hook and recreated it without the Secret. Any other ideas?

Comment: Is your GitHub repo public? I guess it must be since you mentioned you can trigger the build from the repo manually.

Comment: Yes, at the moment it is public. I thought I would get it working for the 'easy' situation first and then make it private etc.

Comment: I was NOT using the 'master' branch on git. I changed it to use the 'master' branch on Eclipse and at GitHub and got rid of the other branch completely. NOW IT WORKS!!! Thanks luciddreamz...

Comment: Got it - I'm sure someone else will eventually have a similar question about the secret, content type, or branch related issues :)